# Admin menu bar dropdown opens when I click on a form <select> element (Chrome)

Tags: admin-menu, dropdown, select, google-chrome

Whenever I click on a `<select>` element within a form, it opens not only the relevant dropdown but at the same time the first dropdown menu of the admin menu bar.

It seems to be an issue with *Google Chrome*, as this doesn't happen with *Firefox*.

Does anyone else have the same issue ? Any ideas about how to fix it ?

Comment: Yep; I've seen exactly the same thing. No idea what causes it. Might be worth submitting a bug report in Trac?

Comment: I looked and it has been submitted already, ex [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15848) and [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17681).

Comment: So should we chalk this one up to being a bug? How do we handle what are essentially bug reports on WPSE?

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed, so I think it is not relevant anymore.

Comment: I dunno what's happening, but I am experiencing this bug in chrome (don't know if it's webkit or only chrome) with two of my recent 3.4.2 installs, one on a production site. Mike or @Chip - have you stumbled upon a solution for this crappola?